# What data attribute to use when returning application/pdf?

Tags: angularjs

I am returning an array of bytes from a web api method that sets content-type as 'application/octet-stream. This array of bytes is for a pdf file. I am using angularjs.

**Question** : What will be the data value for href in code below for this case? I have set its as attachment/pdf which is not working.

```
 return reportsDataService.getMyData()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        var element = angular.element('<a/>');
                        element.attr({
                            href: 'data:attachment/pdf,' + url,
                            target: '_blank',
                            download: 'myreport.pdf'
                        })[0].click();
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) documentation, you can code as below

```
var blob = new Blob([typedArray], {type: 'application/octet-binary'});
$scope.url= URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Then in your view

```
<a download="content.txt" ng-href="{{ url }}">download</a>
```

Last but not least, you should configure the `compileProvider` to enable the url

```
app.config(['$compileProvider',
function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|blob):/);
}]);
```